# MS Project 2013 Error Loading Saved Query for TFS Integration

Tags: tfs, ms-project

I am trying to set up an integration with MS Project 2013 with TFS 2017 I have not tried this before. so i am not sure if there is a problem with my pc setup or the addin configuration.This is the error i get when trying to open saved query:

Error Converting Value "System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity;xxx" to type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Identity.Services.IdentityDiscriptor'.Path 'authenticatedUser.descriptor'. line 1 postion 168

I am able to load it from Visual Studio 2015 in the workitems load the Query and then click "Open in Microsoft Office" then choose MS Project. this loads successfully. but i do get errors that I can't publish changes. It asked to restart Project and try again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue came back and did some more google searches. I found the answer as part of a bug kb
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3181963/excel-or-project-cannot-connect-to-tfs-2010-or-tfs-2012-servers

After installing this update and rebooting it works.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce this issue with project 2013 and TFS 2017.

Check Addins’ key in registry (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\MS Project\Addins), change newest addin (e.g. TFCOfficeShim.Connect.5) LoadBehavior to 3 and others to 0, then try to open saved query in Project 2013 and check the result.

If still don’t work, try to repair your project product.

Comment: In the Registry i don't see TFCOfficeShim.Connect.5  . currently i have TFCOfficeShim.Connect.14 with LoadBehavior  = 3, TFCOfficeShim.Connect.3 with LoadBehavior  = 0, TFCOfficeShim.Connect.4 with LoadBehavior  = 0

Comment: @greektreat I am afraid that you need to repair project.

Answer (score 0):

I have uninstalled Office 365 and Project 2013. Restarted my PC and installed Project 2013 and this fixed this issue.